# Importing MariaDB into Mysql in Wordpress

Tags: mysql

VVV for Vagrant now comes with MariaDB by default.

If I work locally for developing a Wordpress site and then want to import the database to a production environment. Will the import be compatible or is this bad practices?

Thanks

Comment: MariaDB & MySQL has identical SQL syntax. So should be fine.

Comment: BTW, there is nothing wrong in using MariaDB in production as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While at the current point in time there is very little difference, and maybe no difference at all, this is a bad practice if your development environment supposed to replicate the server your code will run on.

There is just no point in forking a product without having the intention to change it, and the changes might be explicit as different toolset commands or SQL syntax changes, or hidden like better/worse performance for some queries.

For 99% of the wordpress oriented development it makes no difference, but it always sucks to discover your current specific project is in the 1% only when you are running into problems (which usually comes when you have no time to waste on such things).

Comment: Thanks. I am thinking of switching from VVV Vagrant to Mamp just because of the 1% you mention. For Wordpress I don't think it needs to match exactly, but I would like the PHP version, Apache vs Nginx, and database to match at least.

Comment: PHP version is really a must. web server you probably want to be the same type and version especially if you do anything which is related to webserver config

Comment: Thanks again. I gotta choose a local dev strategy and then stick with it. I've spent hours on this. lol. Now, i've run into Local by Flywheel.